# Javascript loading css styles for different screen resolution is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

With the screen resolution of 13**66**x768, the following javascript will load the styles intended for a 13**60**x768 screen resolution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ((screen.width = 1366)&&(screen.height = 768)) {
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_1366.css" type="text/css" />');
}

if ((screen.width = 1360)&&(screen.height = 768)) {
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_1360.css" type="text/css" />');
}
</script>
```

Would you be kind enough to please help me regarding this script?

Thank you very much,

Bat

Comment: You're using simple equals, which result in an assignation, not an equality test...

Comment: As jiowcs said, `screen.width = 1366` is assigning the value `1366` to `screen.width = 1366` because `=` is the assignment operator. You want the comparison operator `==` which will evaluate to true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparing use doubled equals sign ==

Comment: Works great! Now I have to find a way to make it work on Iexplore 8! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have better results if you use media queries to determine what to show. This is the pure css way. e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1360px) {
}
```